# Several Independent ForEach in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I need to have several ForEach in the same SSIS, which are not dependent on each other - if one fails, I want the other ones to run. Each ForEach will have others tasks on failure or success (send emails, etc). So I was thinking of putting each ForEach inside seperate Sequence Containers, so they run in a specific order as opposed of all at the same time. But I cannot tell the Sequence to run the next one on both success and fail.

Which would be the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence constraint statuses are Success, Fail and Complete. Complete is whether it Succeeds or Fails.

Comment: Do I need to increase the number of MaximumErrorCount to the number of Containers? What I mean is, if I have 3 containers, should I set MaximumErrorCount to 2 because, even when it's going to continue to the next container no matter what, the number of errors will be higher than 1 and it will stop. Or does the number of MaximumErrorCount is per container?